# How to create multiple task groups in airflow with parallel tasks

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

Please refer the code snippet below. I am trying to create DAG as per diagram 1 , however my code is creating the DAG as diagram 2. Please advise.

Code:

```
task_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
parallel_task_per_grp = 3
task_grp_cnt = math.ceil(len(task_list)/parallel_task_per_grp)
task_grp_names = [f"grp_{tgc}" for tgc in range(task_grp_cnt)]

with DAG(
        dag_id=dag_name_id,
        default_args=default_args,
        start_date=start_date,
        schedule_interval=None,    # mi hr dy mn wd - as per cron
        tags=["adhoc_dag_ing_conf_sys_profile_col_upd"],
        catchup=False
) as dag:
    start = BashOperator(task_id="start", bash_command='echo "starting batch processing"', do_xcom_push=False)
    stop = BashOperator(task_id="stop", bash_command='echo "stopping batch processing"', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_SKIPPED, do_xcom_push=False)

    start_pos, stop_pos = 0, parallel_task_per_grp
    task_group = []
    for task_grp_name in task_grp_names:
        with TaskGroup(group_id=task_grp_name) as tg1:
            [DummyOperator(task_id=f"task_{tl}") for tl in task_list[start_pos:stop_pos]]
        task_group.append(tg1)
        start_pos, stop_pos = start_pos+parallel_task_per_grp, stop_pos+parallel_task_per_grp

    start >> task_group >> stop
```

Diagram 1

[image]

Diagram 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
start_pos, stop_pos = 0, parallel_task_per_grp
    task_group = []
    for task_grp_name in task_grp_names:
        with TaskGroup(group_id=task_grp_name) as tg1:
            [DummyOperator(task_id=f"task_{tl}") for tl in task_list[start_pos:stop_pos]]
        task_group.append(tg1)
        start_pos, stop_pos = start_pos+parallel_task_per_grp, stop_pos+parallel_task_per_grp

    chain(*task_group)

    start_processing >> task_group[0]
    task_group[-1] >> stop_processing
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**